# Angularjs: Template side if form is valid fire onchange

Tags: angularjs, validation

```
<input type='email' required ng-model='email' onchange='onlyfirewheninputvalid(email)'>
```

This is for a simple signup form. The user starts typing into the email input, and as soon as the email is valid type, I fire an ajax call to see if the email exists already.

In an effort to keep my controller testable without the template, I am struggling to find a way to hold the onchange unless the input is valid, completely from the template side.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, by default change does not fire unless the input is valid. So, yeah...